# Issue with converting to timestamp

Tags: timestamp, teradata

I have one issue with timestamp column.The below query is working fine:

```
SEL

CASE WHEN CHARACTER_LENGTH(TO_CHAR(SRC.TXN_DT))=7 THEN CAST(SRC.TXN_DT AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') ELSE  CURRENT_DATE END
||' '|| (CASE WHEN SRC.TXN_TM=0 THEN '00:00:00' ELSE  (SRC.TXN_TM (FORMAT '99:99:99')) END)   FROM TU_82933_L_ZA_CCDB .T_SF_INT SRC
```

However, when i am trying to cast the whole thing into varchar and then again to timestamp(0) it is giving invalid timestamp. I have checked my data there are no more bad records.

```
SEL
CAST(
CAST(
CASE WHEN CHARACTER_LENGTH(TO_CHAR(SRC.TXN_DT))=7 THEN CAST(SRC.TXN_DT AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') ELSE  CURRENT_DATE END
||' '|| (CASE WHEN SRC.TXN_TM=0 THEN '00:00:00' ELSE  (SRC.TXN_TM ( FORMAT '99:99:99')) END)   AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TIMESTAMP(0)  FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS')
FROM TU_82933_L_ZA_CCDB .T_Q17020_Q90TXNO_OAS_SF_INT SRC
```

Can anyone help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix different date formats, `'MM/DD/YYYY'` and `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

What's the datatype of `SRC.TXN_DT`, it's a `DATE` or an `INT`?
I don't think that `CHARACTER_LENGTH(TO_CHAR(SRC.TXN_DT))` will ever return `7`, should be always `10` (at least that matches the format you use in `THEN`.

And there's no reason to do the 2nd `CASE` using `SRC.TXN_TM=0`. It doesn't matter if it's zero or non-zero, as you apply the same format.

Can you show some actual values and why you think you can't simply concat & cast?

Edit based on comments:

`1160229` is the (stupid) internal storage of a date in Teradata:

```
2016-02-29             =  1160229

(year - 1900) * 10000  =  1160000
+ month * 100            +    200
+ day                    +     29
```

If both columns are INT the most efficient way to convert to timestamps is

```
CAST(CAST(TXN_DT AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP(0))
+ CAST(TRIM(TXN_TM (FORMAT '99:99:99')) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND(0))
```

But your approach should also work, if it fails there's bad data, that's the penalty for storing date & time as integers :)

If you don't do calculations you might simply convert to a string which looks like a timestamp:

```
(TXN_DT + 19000000 (FORMAT '9999-99-99')) || (TXN_TM (FORMAT 'Z99:99:99'))
```

Comment: Hi Dieter,
Thanks for replying.
Both SRC.TXN_DT and SRC.TXN_TM are integers.Sample Values:
1160228 115646
1160228 93816

Comment: I have used the second case because TXN_TM has few zeros. Just to filter those. 
Also, I am not very sure how 1160229 is converted as 29/02/2016

Comment: wow.. Thanks Dieter for the explaination :). I will try this once and come back to you :) thanks again.